# Rails API: 406 Not Acceptable in 20ms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build an API for RoR app. I have the following:

1. app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb:

   ```
   module Api
     class BaseController < ApplicationController
       respond_to :json
     end
   end
   ```
2. app/controllers/api/orders_controller.rb

   ```
   module Api
     class OrdersController < Api::BaseController

       def get_orders
           os = Order.last
           @order = Hash.new
           @order["number"] = os.number
           @order["id"] = os.id
           respond_to do |format|
               format.json { render json: @order }
           end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. config/routes.rb

   ```
   namespace :api do
     match "/get_orders" => "orders#get_orders"
   end
   ```

But when I go to "localhost:3000/api/get_orders", I get a `406`:

> Started GET "/api/get_orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 12:19:40
>   +0530   Tag Load (170.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT(tags.tag_name) FROM "tags" WHERE (tags.taggable_type = 'Product')   Processing by
>   Api::OrdersController#get_orders as HTML   Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT
>   "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1 Completed
>   406 Not Acceptable in 24ms

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, the line

```
respond_to :json
```

Means that it should *only* respond to requests using the JSON format. If you request any other format (such as HTML), you will get a 406 Not Acceptable.

Try requesting the page using the JSON extension:

```
localhost:3000/api/get_orders.json
```